# Random Number generated from Normal Distribution N(0,1)

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation

If we generated random number from Normal Distribution N(0,1) that is always positive by using Uniform Dist from 0.5 to 1, Is it still follow normal distribution the data that we are generated?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you generated random values following normal distribution then they follow normal distribution, if not, they do not. It is also unclear what is "always positive by using Uniform Dist from 0.5 to 1".

Comment: Are you asking that if you use the Probability Integral Transform to generate data from a normal distribution and only take values from .5. to 1 from the Uniform Distribution if the resulting data would also follow A Normal Distribution?

Comment: @StatsStudent yup that is it. if we generated the data from .5 to 1, is the data still follow the a normal distribution?

Comment: @srimaster, then Glen_b's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if $V\sim U(\frac12,1)$, the values you get by $\Phi^{-1}(V)$ will indeed be positive, but they will not have a normal distribution.

Just as you cut the standard uniform in half, you have also cut the normal in half:

[image: truncated uniform and half-normal]

The right half of a normal distribution isn't a normal distribution.

No normal distribution is entirely positive. If that's what you're trying for, you have to give up something -- either it's not exactly normal or there's some chance it's negative.